# Where are the imaginary numbers in Fourier analysis hiding?

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-numbers

Someone (in an ancient closed thread) said, **"Fourier analysis is simplified if complex numbers are used."**

Hey, wait, you separate the frequency components of a wave to represent it as a power spectrum. Where does $\sqrt{-1}$ appear in all this? Is it deep in the arithmetic of the FFT software, or does $i$ have some observable influence on the transformed wave?

Comment: A power spectrum is the absolute value squared of a Fourier transform.

Answer (score 9):

[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) tells us that

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$

Using complex numbers allows us to handle $\sin$ and $\cos$ waves at the same time in areas such as [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis). It also suggests conceptual links between, for example, Fourier transforms and [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Answer (score 1):

What Gandalf said.
Real Fourier series look like
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)
$$
whereas complex Fourier series look like
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n x}
$$
We can convert from one to the other using
$$
e^{inx} = \cos (nx) + i \sin (nx),\qquad
\cos (nx) = \frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2},\qquad
\sin (nx) = \frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}
$$

Answer (score 0):

See the Hartley transform for an equivalent frequency domain analysis without imaginary numbers. i is the sqrt of negative one; multiplying i by itself over and over again produces an oscillating negative sign which also occurs when one repeatedly differentiates sine.  i is a notational convenience.